# Generating pivot table in PostgreSQL that ties cities to counties using QGIS (or PostGIS)?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a cities shapefile and a counties shapefile. I have the counties shapefile imported to a PostgreSQL table. I haven't transferred my cities to PostgreSQL yet, but the issue I really want to figure out is how do I create a third table.

Since cities and townships often overlap several counties, I ultimately want a `cities` table, a `counties` table, and a `city_county` pivot table (ID, CITY_ID, COUNTY_ID) so it will play fair with my web application (Laravel Eloquent ORM).

I've been looking through QGIS and can't seem to figure it out, but even if I can accomplish this with SQL in PostgreSQL/PostGIS, that'd be great.

Comment: This is just a simple spatial join in CREATE TABLE AS query.  Load the second table and start by researching  a 1:M/M:M join on ST_Intersects.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is something like this - replace 4326 with the srid of your data.

```
CREATE TABLE city_county AS
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cities.gid, counties.gid) As gid,
         cities.gid As city_id, counties.gid AS county_id,
         ST_Multi(
              ST_Intersection(counties.geom, cities.geom)
              )::geometry(Multipolygon, 4326)  AS geom
FROM cities INNER JOIN counties 
ON (ST_Covers(counties.geom, cities.geom)  
      OR ST_Overlaps(counties.geom, cities.geom ) );
```

Note I use overlap and covers instead of ST_Intersects because you don't want to join couties and cities that just share a border.

Then you just add a spatial index to your geometry column and and primary key and you should be good to go.